# ¿como hacer que los valores no se borren en un txt en c?

Tags: base-de-datos, c, estructuras-de-datos

Necesito crear una lista de alumnos y poder agregar las personas que desee sin eliminar las que ya están  pero al momento de ingresar los valores y cerrar el programa vuelvo a correrlo, se borra lo que había en el txt si vuelvo a pedir los nombres, apellidos y clave.
ademas de como comparar los apellidos y nombres en caso de que ya estén en la lista ya que es para hacer una lista de asistencia de semanal, el mostrartodos lo pongo en los comentarios

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define personas 3

struct datos{

    char apellido[30];
    char nombre[30];
    int clave;
};
void capturar(){
        FILE *archivo =fopen("lista.txt","w");
    struct datos alumnos[personas];
    int indice = 0;
    char agregar;

    do
    {

        while(getchar() != '\n');
        printf("Ingresa el apellido  #%d",(indice+1));
        fgets(alumnos[indice].apellido, 30, stdin);
        printf("Ingresa el nombre #%d",(indice+1));
        fgets(alumnos[indice].nombre, 30, stdin);
        printf("Ingresa clave #%d",(indice+1));
        scanf("%d",&alumnos[indice].clave);
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        fprintf(archivo,"\n %s %s  %i",alumnos[indice].apellido,alumnos[indice].nombre, alumnos[indice].clave);
        indice++;
        printf(" desea agregar otro alumno s/n \n");
        scanf("%c",&agregar);

    }while(agregar!='n');

    fclose(archivo);
}

void menu(){
    int opcion;
    char seguir;
    do{
    printf("Seleccione\n");
    scanf("%d",&opcion);
    switch(opcion){
        case 1:
            capturar();
            break;

        case 3:
            mostrarTodos();
            break;

        default:
            printf("OPCION INVALIDA");
    }
    printf("quiere ver algo mas? ");
    scanf("%s",&seguir);
    }while(seguir='s');  
}

int main(){

    menu();

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: void mostrarTodos(){
    
        FILE *archivo =fopen("lista.txt","r");
        if(archivo==NULL){
            perror("error");
        }
        int numero;
        char ap[15],nom[15];
        while(feof(archivo)==0){
            
            fscanf(archivo,"%s %s %i",ap,nom,&numero);
            printf("%i %s %s \n",numero,ap,nom);
            
        }
        
        fclose(archivo);
        printf("\n   \n");

    
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si consultamos la documentación de [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen), vemos que abrir un archivo en modo `"w"` destruye el contenido previo del archivo:

| Modo | Significado | Explicación | Acción si el archivo existe | Acción si el archivo no existe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `"r"` | Lectura | Abre el archivo para leerlo | Lee desde el inicio | Error |
| `"w"` | Escritura | Crea el archivo para escribir | Destruye el contenido | Crea archivo |
| `"a"` | Añade | Añade al archivo | Escribe desde el final | Crea archivo |

Así que si quieres añadir nuevos datos al archivo, lo que debes hacer es abrirlo en modo `"a"`. Pero tampoco te sirve para tu último objetivo.

Si quieres mantener una colección de datos que pueda crecer, menguar y cambiar, tu código debe comportarse de la siguiente manera:

1. Leer **todos** los datos desde archivo a memoria.
2. Hacer todas las operaciones de añadir, eliminar o modificar registros en memoria (no en archivo).
3. Guardar **todos** los datos desde memoria a archivo en el momento de finalizar la ejecución.

Answer (score 1):

Una mejor manera de hacer lo que intentas es declarar como ya hiciste tu estructura, pero además, un arreglo en el que puedas almacenar diferentes estructuras dentro, para que así tengas todas las estructuras que necesitas, para esto necesitas una llamada a un módulo al inicio de tu programa y otra al final, la del inicio guardará todos los datos (en caso de existir) dentro de tu arreglo y la del final guardará todos los datos de tu arreglo dentro de tu archivo.

Sizeof te da un tamaño específico de bytes que ocupará tu estructura, esto para que se almacene en ese tamaño de bytes en tu archivo, además, el archivo conviene ser creado de forma binaria con "wb+"

Además nota como puedes aprovechar el valor que regresa la apertura de un archivo para hacer una condición y no realizar instrucciones de más

```
Nombre de tu módulo
{
    TrMaestro rMaestro;
    TfArchivo fArchivoMaestros;

    if((fArchivoMaestros = fopen("Maestros.txt", "rb+")) == NULL) // && (fArchivoMaestros = fopen("Maestros.txt", "ab+")) == NULL
    {
        printf("El arcihvo todavía no existe.");
        getch();


    } else {

        rewind(fArchivoMaestros);

        while(! feof(fArchivoMaestros))
        {
            fread(&rMaestro, sizeof(rMaestro), 1, fArchivoMaestros);
            insertarMaestro(aMaestros, eTotalMaestros, rMaestro);
        }

        fclose(fArchivoMaestros);
    }
}




Nombre de tu módulo
{
    TrMaestro rMaestro;
    int eVaciando, eValorTotal;
    TfArchivo fArchivoMaestros;

    if(eTotalMaestros != -1)
    {
        if((fArchivoMaestros = fopen("Maestros.txt", "wb+")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("No se han podido almacenar los datos de esta ejecución.");

        } else {

            printf("Has regresado al menú principal.");
            system("pause > NULL");

            eVaciando = 0;

            while(eVaciando <= eTotalMaestros)
            {
                rMaestro = aMaestros[eVaciando];



                fwrite(&rMaestro, sizeof(rMaestro), 1, fArchivoMaestros);

                eVaciando ++;
            }

            fclose(fArchivoMaestros);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es un módulo? O_o

Comment: me aparece que el Tr y Tf no son validos , tengo que poner una libreria o como declararlos en otro lado?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Módulo en programación, significa separar el problema del problema principal. En este caso Luis se refiere a separarlo a través de funciones.

Comment: @MrDave1999 módulo en [tag:C++] es una propuesta para cambiar el sistema de compilación y enlazado sobre la que se lleva trabajando desde 2017. También es un tipo mueble (aunque eso no tiene que ver con C++). En cuanto a [tag:C] no tengo ni idea de lo que es, pero si el autor se refiere a funciones ¿Por qué no redactar una función en lugar de poner el texto `Nombre de tu módulo`,  haciendo el código completamente incompilable?

Comment: Eso es solo una forma de declarar un tipo de dato para tu estructura y otro para tu archivo, para que no tengas que estar poniendo "struct tal" y solo pongas "tal" y el otro es para que no tengas que estar poniendo FILE *ArchivoMaestro" si no solo TfArchivo fArchivoMaestro en todas partes y ya.

En este caso mi TrMaestro significa que es un registro de rMaestro y pues TfArchivo es para no estar poniendo esto: FILE *TfArchivo y solo poner esto una vez: typedef FILE *TfArchivo;

Comment: No he preguntado por los alias de las estructuras, pregunté por ¿Qué es `Nombre de tu módulo`?

Comment: Pues el nombre que le quieras asignar a dicha función para que tu mismo la declares en la cabecera de tu código